# C# Right usage for (number & number) from C++?

Tags: c#, c++

I have the following C++ lines:

```
if(fromPos.x == 0xFFFF){
        if(fromPos.y & 0x40){
            fromIndex = static_cast<uint8_t>(fromPos.z);
        }
        else{
            fromIndex = static_cast<uint8_t>(fromPos.y);
        }
    }
    else
        fromIndex = fromStackPos;
```

but I have no idea how to make use of fromPos.y & 0x40 in C#, doing it the way it is in C++ doesn't work on CSharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, the condition in an `if` statement doesn't have to be a Boolean expression - but it does in C#. You just need to check for the result being non-zero:

```
if ((fromPos.y & 0x40) != 0)
```

(The brackets are required due to precedence; `!=` binds tighter than `&`.)